# get contents of a link with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, innertext

How can I use PHP (javascript is fine too) to get the data from this?

```
    <div class="row first-row">
<a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-hiscores/ranking?clanId=346923&amp;ranking=num_members">
<div class="left">
<p>
Clanmates
</p>
<span>
165
</span>
</div>
</a>
<div class="middle">
<img src="http://www.runescape.com/img/clan/stats/stats/num_members.png" alt="" title="Clanmates">
</div>
</div>
```

(note i ruined it because it parsed)

I want to return that '165' automatically, because it changes.

Sorry for asking a stupid question, searching google and this site doesn't come up with what I need.

I am new at this :/

Comment: Is the HTML really that mal-formed?

Comment: The edit to this question should not have been approved.

Comment: @BenM It got rolled back and fixed; OP updated it.

Comment: Can you post the actual html and the html that surrounds it?

Comment: @user Please post that in your question; it is not displaying correctly in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML in question and extract the link text. Without more code or more information on what you are trying to do, it is hard to give a full answer.

**EDIT:** Here is a working example with DOMDocument:

```
<?php

// Replace this with your actual HTML
$str = '<td class="col3 align"><a href="http://somesite.com/">165</a></td>';

// Create an instance of DOMDocument
$html = new DOMDocument();
// load and parse your HTML
$html->loadHTML($str);
// Get the a tags
$a_tags = $html->getElementsByTagName('a');
// Loop through them
foreach ($a_tags as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue, PHP_EOL; // prints 165
}
```

*IF* the code really is broken HTML like in the sample you gave, you might be able to use a regular expression, like this:

```
$str = 'td class="col3 align">a href="http://somesite.com/">165</a</td ';
$text = preg_replace('~^.+?a[^>]+>|</a.+$~', '', $str);
```

Comment: You could also use something like [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

Comment: yea that doesn't help.. show/point me to me an example please? i can never understand the php site..

Comment: @BenM It sounds like the HTML may have gotten busted when it was pasted here, but I edited my answer in case it really is that busted.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it in jQuery like this:

```
var url = $('.col3.align a').text();
```

Comment: Yep, sorry, my bad :) Edited the answer.